# How can I add a small matrix into a bigger one along the diagonal in a specific way?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to write a big matrix that includes a smaller row matrix (size changeable) that are spread on the "diagonal" of the matrix. All the other values are 0. How do I create such a matrix?

I've tried np.put, np.append. Here's what I have so far:

```
t = [1,2,3] 

n=3

m=4

A = np.zeros((2*m,m*n+m),dtype=int)

for i in range (m):
    A[i-1:i-1+t.shape[0], n*(i-1):n*(i-1)+t.shape[1]] += t
print("A= \n",np.matrix(A))
```

I want the following matrix (I'm sorry I don't know how to show matrix but if someone can help me with this too I would appreciate it a lot) :

```
A= 

 [[1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

 [0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]

 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0 0]

 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

It causes the following error:

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,0) (1,3) (0,0)

Comment: _

"_I am trying to write a big matrix that includes a smaller row matrix (size changeable) that are spread on the "diagonal" of the matrix. All the other values are 0. How do I create such matrix?_" I'm having trouble  understanding what that means. Are you simply looking to create that specific matrix?

Comment: Why is the fifth list not `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 0]`

Comment: I want to create this specific matrix. It is not what you gave me is because I created this for a simplex resolution and I have to leave that part null.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily answer my question about why the fifth list down, which is currently `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]` does not match the template `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 0]`

Comment: Is there a mathematical term for this operation that needs to be generalized, or do you just need to have this matrix? In my work with simplex transformation to cartesian coordiantes, you need to do the dot product of two matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Make mask for 12 positions and use it for assignment

```
idx = np.zeros(A.shape).astype(bool)
for i in range(m):
    idx[i,i*n:i*n+3] = True
A[idx]= t*m

array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: The fourth line is wrong and does not match OP's intended array.

Comment: got lost in params. Updated

Comment: That is pretty good, but from the second line, the row starts 1 column after the wanted column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use careful reshaping like so:

```
t = [1,2,3]     
n=3
m=4
A = np.zeros((2*m,m*n+m),dtype=int)

A.ravel()[:m*(m*n+m+n)].reshape(m,-1)[:,:len(t)] = t
A
# array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```